# Cross-thread InvalidOperationException when logging to MyLogger from a background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, thread-safety, richtextbox

I have created a event driven logger that seems to have issues when called from another thread. How can I make it thread safe?

Here is the LoggerClass:

```
public static class MyLogger
{
    private static List<string> log = new List<string>();
    public static event EventHandler LogAdded;
    private static string indent = "";

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        log.Add(indent + message);
        if (LogAdded != null)
            LogAdded(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In my form class I initiated it in the following two ways:

```
public frm_main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyLogger.LogAdded += new EventHandler(MyLogger_LogAdded);
}
```

And here is the event progress where the crash occurs:

```
private void MyLogger_LogAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int length = rtb_logger.TextLength;  // at end of text
    string prefix = string.Format("{0:d3}: ", ++logindex);
    string ToAppend = prefix + MyLogger.GetLastLog();
    rtb_logger.AppendText(ToAppend);
    if (ToAppend.Contains("Alert -"))
    {
        rtb_logger.SelectionStart = length;
        rtb_logger.SelectionLength = ToAppend.Length;
        rtb_logger.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
    rtb_logger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    rtb_logger.SelectionStart = rtb_logger.TextLength;
    rtb_logger.ScrollToCaret();
    EnableControls();
}
```

The crash occurs on the first line abobve commented with "at end of text" in the following call from the backgroundworker:

```
MyLogger.Log("Sending cmd: \"" + strCmdText + "\" to CMD.exe.");
```

How do I make MyLogger class thread-safe?

**Edit:** Going with SeeSharp solution, code changed is:

```
private void MyLogger_LogAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rtb_logger.InvokeRequired)
    {
        rtb_logger.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate {
            MyLogger_LogAdded(sender, e);
        }));
        return;
    }
    int length = rtb_logger.TextLength;  // at end of text
    string prefix = string.Format("{0:d3}: ", ++logindex);
    string ToAppend = prefix + MyLogger.GetLastLog();
    rtb_logger.AppendText(ToAppend);
    if (ToAppend.Contains("Alert -"))
    {
        rtb_logger.SelectionStart = length;
        rtb_logger.SelectionLength = ToAppend.Length;
        rtb_logger.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
    rtb_logger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    rtb_logger.SelectionStart = rtb_logger.TextLength;
    rtb_logger.ScrollToCaret();
    EnableControls();
}
```

Comment: rtb_logger - RichTextBox? Wpf or WinForms?

Comment: Just goodle or search over SO for `control+begininvoke`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call body of MyLogger_LogAdded in UI thread.
Try to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() when you call methods or properties of rtb_logger.

See [C#: Thread safe richtextbox event logging method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418845/c-thread-safe-richtextbox-event-logging-method/418880#418880)

Answer (score 0):

```
private delegate void MYLOGGEREVENT(object sender, EventArgs e);
private void MyLogger_LogAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MYLOGGEREVENT(MyLogger_LogAdded), new object[]{sender, e});
            }
else{
    int length = rtb_logger.TextLength;  // at end of text
    string prefix = string.Format("{0:d3}: ", ++logindex);
    string ToAppend = prefix + MyLogger.GetLastLog();
    rtb_logger.AppendText(ToAppend);
    if (ToAppend.Contains("Alert -"))
    {
        rtb_logger.SelectionStart = length;
        rtb_logger.SelectionLength = ToAppend.Length;
        rtb_logger.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
    rtb_logger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    rtb_logger.SelectionStart = rtb_logger.TextLength;
    rtb_logger.ScrollToCaret();
    EnableControls();
}
}
```

try this.